# Why doesn't the columns have fixed size?

Tags: html, css, blogspot

My friend has a blogspot blog. On my computer, everything looks good but the three columns she uses become smaller on hers like this:

[image]That's mine.

[image]And that's hers.

On the left there's an image as background and the other two is the main section where the posts are and a sidebar on the right side.

And I found these text in the middle of the code:

> Show image as background to text. You can't really calculate the width
>   reliably in JS because margins are not taken into account by any of
>   clientWidth, offsetWidth or scrollWidth, so we don't force a minimum
>   width if the user is using shrink to fit. This results in a
>   margin-width's worth of pixels being cropped. If the user is not using
>   shrink to fit then we expand the header.

I'm not very great in these things so I have no idea what should I do. Any guesses?

Comment: Need some code to help you debug this, you've not really provided enough to suggest a solution - chances are whatever theme you have on your blogspot is not responsive

Comment: Maybe ur using pixels for positioning your elements but her screen is bigger :D